# Writing with too many system calls

Tags: c, file-system

I have a `writeOnFile()` method with too many `fwrite()`.
I think it is not a good implementation because too many system calls may produce a high overhead.

What can I do?

---

### Code

```c
void writeOnFile()
{
    char cr[1] = {'\n'};    //Usefull characters
    char sp[1] = {' '};


    char header1[] = "Instant        ";             //Headers
    fwrite(header1, 1, strlen(header1), out);
    char header2[] = "Playing (1 yes, 0 no)    ";
    fwrite(header2, 1, strlen(header2), out);
    char header3[] = "Segment ID    ";
    fwrite(header3, 1, strlen(header3), out);
    char header4[] = "Encode level\n";
    fwrite(header4, 1, strlen(header4), out);

    char strNumber[50];                             //Data writing
    for (int i = 0; i < global_index; i++)
    {
        snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%f", instants[i]);
        fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
        //Adds spaces
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header1) - strlen(strNumber); i++)
            fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);

        snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%d", playing[i]);
        fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header2) - strlen(strNumber); i++)
            fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);

        snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%li", segment_index[i]);
        fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
        fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header3) - strlen(strNumber) - 1; i++)
            fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);

        snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%d", encode_level_buff[i]);
        fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);

        //Inserts a \n at the end of the row but not at the end of file
        if (i != global_index - 1)            
            fwrite(cr, 1, 1, out);
    }
}
```

### Output example

[image]

Comment: You could greatly simplify your code - and gain the benefit of buffering - If you use `fprintf` and its variants instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: Isn't `fwrite` buffered as well? To actually count the number of system calls, use a tool such as `strace`, `truss` or `ktrace`.

Comment: Why "Inserts a \n at the end of the row but not at the end of file"?  Far more common to desire a final `'\n'`.

Comment: The variable: `int i`, in all but the first `for()` statement, is shadowing the initial `i` variable.  This can result in problems.  Suggest all but the first `for()` loop use `int j`  However, the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t` so the variable `i` and `j` should be defined as: `size_t i` and `size_t j`

Comment: when ever calling: `fwrite()`, always check the returned value ( if not the same as the 3rd parameters, then some error has occurred.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a writeOnFile() method with too many fwrite().  ...

A way to reduce `fwrite()` calls is to simply write all text to a large `char buffer[]` and then write that once per `for (int i = 0; i < global_index; i++)` loop.

Use the return vale of `snprintf()` to speed calculation of next offset.  Use  `*printf()` features for padding.

```
for (int i = 0; i < global_index; i++) {
    char buf[N];
    int offset = 0;

    //snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%f", instants[i]);
    //fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
    //for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header1) - strlen(strNumber); i++)
    //    fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);

    //                                           vv---- pad on right
    int len = snprintf(buf+offset, N - offset, "%-*f", (int) (sizeof header1 - 1), instants[i]);
    assert(len >= 0 && len < N - offset);
    offset += len;

    //snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%d", playing[i]);
    //fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
    //for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header2) - strlen(strNumber); i++)
    //    fwrite(sp, 1, 1, out);

    len = snprintf(buf+offset, N - offset, "%-*d", (int) (sizeof header2 - 1), playing[i]);
    assert(len >= 0 && len < N - offset);
    offset += len;

    ....

    fwrite(buf, 1, offset, out);
}
```

---

Some other ideas to linearly improve performance.

**Why run down string again to find length?**

```
//snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%f", instants[i]);
//fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
int len = snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%f", instants[i]);
fwrite(strNumber, 1, len, out);
```

**No need for `strlen()` for a constant string**

```
char header1[] = "Instant        ";
// fwrite(header1, 1, strlen(header1), out);
fwrite(header1, 1, sizeof header1 - 1, out);
```

**Questionable "safe:" concerns**

`sprintf()` is certainly faster (or as fast) as `snprintf()` ....

```
// snprintf(strNumber, 50, "%d", playing[i]);
sprintf(strNumber, "%d", playing[i]);
```

... yet by some coding standards, better to use `snprintf()` even though `"%d"` will not overfill 50 `char` array.

What is curious about this "safe" code is the lack of checks of `fwrite()` return, a more likely issue.

```
    // fwrite(strNumber, 1, strlen(strNumber), out);
    size_t nmemb = strlen(strNumber);
    size_t written = fwrite(strNumber, 1, nmemb, out);
    if (written != nmemb) Handle_Error();
```

---

**Watch out for *unsigned* bugs**

Consider what happens when `strlen(header1) < strlen(strNumber)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header1) - strlen(strNumber); i++)
```

is like

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(header1) + (SIZE_MAX - strlen(strNumber) - 1); i++)
```

due to *unsigned*  math wrap around.

Better coded as

```
for (size_t i = strlen(strNumber); i < strlen(header1); i++)
// or 
for (size_t i = strlen(strNumber); i < sizeof header1 - 1; i++)
```

---

**Watch out for *long* `"%f"`**

`"%f"`  may takes 100s  of characters for large FP values.

Consider `"%g"`.

---

Curious that OP's code did not start with `fprintf()` rather than `snprintf()/fwrite()`.  This is another option.

Conceptually, `fprintf()` is effectively doing the `char buffer[]` mentioned above albeit without many `fwrite()/fprintf()` calls.

Switching to `fprintf()`  and using the suggested padding format will be sufficient for a first level speed-up.

For me, I do like the idea of writing a *line* with one I/O call.   It is symmetric with the idea of reading one *line* on input code with `fgets()`.